# Access Object by dynamic key undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dictionary-like `Object` in Javascript and when I want to access to the `dict` by a key generated from page, the result is `undefined`:

How can I access the value correctly?

```js
var dict = {
    "red": "yes",
    "blue":  "no"
};

$("#trigger").click(function(){
  alert(dict[$(this).text()]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="trigger">
blue
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are blank spaces in the text. Use `trim()` to remove them

```js
var dict = {
  "red": "yes",
  "blue": "no"
};

$("#trigger").click(function() {
  alert(dict[$(this).text().trim()]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trigger">
blue
</div>
```

Comment: I think in his HTML the trailing characters are actually the carriage return chars (having code of `10`).

Answer (score 0):

It's because of extra spaces, use `trim()` to handle it

```js
var dict = {
    "red": "yes",
    "blue":  "no"
};

$("#trigger").click(function(){
 alert(dict[$(this).text().trim()]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trigger">
blue
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

its have some extra space. use with [`trim()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwir2rHG18HTAhVLP48KHez5AlkQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_trim_string.asp&usg=AFQjCNEDh_x7JMeCVu0sakhKLDvxAVHYaw). it will reduce the spaces

```js
var dict = {
  "red": "yes",
  "blue": "no"
};
$("#trigger").click(function() {
  console.log(dict[$(this).text().trim()])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="trigger">blue</div>
```